# In a template method, Is there a way to check whether the current type is int-variant or float-variant?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement a template method for variable.

But depending on whether the input is a int-variant(char, short, int), I want to handle it somewhat differently from the case when the input is a float-variant (float, double, long double).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To detect types:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_integral
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_floating_point

Also look into [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) and tag dispatch to actually select implementation